# What's the song in Bleach episode 119 from 17:15?

Tags: music, bleach

In episode 119 of *Bleach*, what's the song from 17:15?

Answer (score 2):

It's "Torn apart", the 20th track of *Bleach Original Soundtrack 2* album by Shiro Sagisu.